# How to delete string date older then 2020/11 month in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a database, with around 500k rows, I don't know why but instead of using "Date" type on the column it uses "varchar". Now the date has a format - `01/02/2021 07:08:49 AM`

My question is how should an SQL query look to delete this kind of "old" date rows from the table? Or in another hand how should I convert the column without losing the data and holding the same format to a Date type column?

I tried deleting with something like this:

```
DELETE FROM `visited` WHERE LEFT(`last_visit_date`, 2) != '01' OR LEFT(`last_visit_date`, 2) != '12';
```

However, this didn't fully clean the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to lose the dates with the wrong format, you can update the table:

```
UPDATE visited
SET last_visit_date = STR_TO_DATE(last_visit_date, '%d/%c/%Y %r')
WHERE last_visit_date LIKE '__/__/____ __:__:__ __';
```

and change the data type of the column to `DATETIME` (if all the other values of `last_visit_date` are valid datetimes):

```
ALTER TABLE visited MODIFY last_visit_date DATETIME;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1002191d6dd220960911c521a143118e).

Answer (score 4):

You may use `STR_TO_DATE` in your delete query to convert the text dates to bona fide dates:

```sql
DELETE
FROM visited
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(last_visit_date, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') < '2020-11-01';
```

Note that if your text dates actually have month before day, then use this call to `STR_TO_DATE`:

```sql
STR_TO_DATE(last_visit_date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

Comment: This is m/d/y, the `LEFT(last_visit_date, 2) != '01' AND LEFT(last_visit_date, 2) != '12'` gave me the hint

Comment: I think the complete format should be `'%m/%d/%Y %r'`

Comment: @Cid Yeah...I always forget about `%r`, what I have should be equivalent though.